Integrating VSCode with Solar2d libraries via Lua Language Server extension
I'm working on a piece of software that uses Solar2D game engine.
For Visual Studio Code exists an extension for Solar2D called "Solar2D Editor" but it doesn't provide the possibility to navigate through the Solar2D API.
My question is - is it possible to somehow integrate the LUA extension with Solar2D libraries? I was trying to find a place these libraries resided and add them to Lua.workspace.library setting in VSCode but with no success so far.
